# How do I log submissions?

Tags: html, css

I just want to log submissions to like a txt that I can look at in github, I want a submission form like: Password & email, then when you click okay, it logs it into like a txt file in github, with "email:password" format.. Anyone know how to do this? I would really appreciate it!

Here is my code so far:

```
<div class="shopping-input input-text">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your Minecraft username." name="username" maxlength="16">
</div>
<div class="shopping-continue element_button">
    <div class="l"></div>
    <div class="r"></div>
    <div class="button_block">
        <a>Continue</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please ask a more specific question than, "How would you do this?" What have you tried (show code please)?

Comment: Please i have researched this and I have not found anything! Please just help me! Otherwise I would of not made an account :/

Comment: In more specificly, I want to get the code for a form with "Email" & "Password" then when you press continue, it creates a txt file with the "email:password" format in your webhost

Comment: SO is not a site for us to write out the code for you and teach from scratch. Show us your code, so we know what to build off of.

Comment: <div class="shopping-input input-text">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your Minecraft username." name="username" maxlength="16">
                </div>
<div class="shopping-continue element_button">
                    <div class="l"></div>
                    <div class="r"></div>
                    <div class="button_block">
                        <a>Continue</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

I want to log something like this to a txt file.. But this codes does not work either

Comment: I can't really find anything on the internet, that relates to this, and I would assume you have worked with logging applications..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comments, it seems as though you don't have much experience with forms or web development in general.

You say you want to "log" it to a text file. This is generally not the best idea, because text files are usually easily accessible and readable to the public. It's best to use a database instead.

However, to either use a text file or a database, you're going to need a [*server-side language*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_scripting) that can interact with the server (such as files). The tagged languages "HTML" and "CSS" will not help you out with the form submission — they are *client-side languages* that help with the formatting of the page and only interact with the user to the browser, and cannot edit files.

PHP is an example of a server-side language. You should read up about it and [file IO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php).

---

Assuming you do know how to use PHP, this would be a very simple example:

**HTML FILE: `index.html`**

```
<form action="action.php" method="post">
    Enter your name here: <input name="name" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

**PHP FILE: `action.php`**

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $file_to_write = fopen("name_file.txt","w+");
    fwrite($file_to_write, $name);
    fclose($file_to_write);
?>
```

Comment: I want it to be public. That is the thing, it was supposed to be simple and easy...

Comment: I never mentioned it being secure

Comment: @Hobo OK then, you can still use PHP. But I don't see non-secure forms and user data often.

Comment: The action.php is forbiden

Comment: This is useful. But the php example is not working in my action.php

Comment: @Hobo Do you know how to use PHP? Are you running it on a server?

Comment: I made an action.php on github. I am using github to host

Comment: Github is not a web host for server-side code (like PHP). If you just want a simple form that saves the data somewhere, and you don't want to run your own server, you may want something like http://www.wufoo.com/ instead.

As far as I know, there is no way specifically on GitHub, to have a page that submits submitted data to a file on GitHub.